# React Native image not showing when try to load location from json file

Tags: json, image, react-native, react-native-flatlist

This is a json file that stores a title and a image location for every elements.

```js
[
 {"key": "a", "title": "Bangladesh", "image": "require('./img/bangladesh.jpg')"},
 {"key": "b", "title": "Sports", "image": "require('./img/sports.jpg')"},
 {"key": "c", "title": "Politics", "image": "require('./img/politics.jpg')"},
 {"key": "d", "title": "Entertainment", "image": "require('./img/entertainment.png')"},
 {"key": "e", "title": "Economics", "image": "require('./img/economics.jpg')"},
 {"key": "f", "title": "Technology", "image": "require('./img/technology.jpg')"},
 {"key": "g", "title": "Others", "image": "require('./img/m.jpg')"},
]
```

And Now I want to show all image and title using a Flatlist. Title shows perfectly but image not shows.

```js
<FlatList horizontal= {true}
  data={newsCategory}
 renderItem={({item}) => (
   <TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.option}
   >
      <Image
        style={styles.imgButton}
        source={item.image}
      />
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.title}</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
     )
   }
/>
```

I check that image location comes perfectly from json file but not shows the image. Don't understand why this occurs.

Comment: Is your `img` folder in the same as your component? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Answer (score 4):

remove string from require.

change this

```
[
    {"key": "a", "title": "Bangladesh", "image": "require('./img/bangladesh.jpg')"},
    {"key": "b", "title": "Sports", "image": "require('./img/sports.jpg')"},
    {"key": "c", "title": "Politics", "image": "require('./img/politics.jpg')"},
    {"key": "d", "title": "Entertainment", "image": "require('./img/entertainment.png')"},
    {"key": "e", "title": "Economics", "image": "require('./img/economics.jpg')"},
    {"key": "f", "title": "Technology", "image": "require('./img/technology.jpg')"},
    {"key": "g", "title": "Others", "image": "require('./img/m.jpg')"},
]
```

to this

```
[
    {"key": "a", "title": "Bangladesh", "image": require('./img/bangladesh.jpg')},
    {"key": "b", "title": "Sports", "image": require('./img/sports.jpg')},
    {"key": "c", "title": "Politics", "image": require('./img/politics.jpg')},
    {"key": "d", "title": "Entertainment", "image": require('./img/entertainment.png')},
    {"key": "e", "title": "Economics", "image": require('./img/economics.jpg')},
    {"key": "f", "title": "Technology", "image": require('./img/technology.jpg')},
    {"key": "g", "title": "Others", "image": require('./img/m.jpg')},
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your image source is string. You should eval it.

```
<FlatList horizontal= {true}
  data={newsCategory}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.option}
      >
      <Image
        style={styles.imgButton}
        source={eval(item.image)}
      />
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
     )
   }
/>
```